# Cowboy server cannot find jsx dependency

Tags: erlang, jsx, cowboy

I can use jiffy ok, but jsx I get

```
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
(tunnel@127.0.0.1)1>  jsx:decode(<<"{\"library\": \"jsx\", \"awesome\": true}">>).
** exception error: undefined function jsx:decode/1
```

Why can I not use jsx?

```
~/tunnel:.ls deps
cowboy  cowlib  jiffy   jsx ranch
~/tunnel:.cat Makefile
PROJECT = tunnel
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = Tunnel
PROJECT_VERSION = 0.1.0

DEPS = cowboy jiffy jsx
dep_cowboy_commit = master

dep_jiffy = git https://github.com/davisp/jiffy
deps_jsx = git https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx#encoder3-decoder3--parser

include erlang.mk
```

Comment: How are you starting the shell? Does the `deps/jsx/ebin` directory exist and does it have `.beam` files in it? There is a typo in your `Makefile`, `deps_jsx` shoudl be `dep_jsx`.

Comment: I missed that typo, I will try that! I'm using `gmake run`